# Is there a way to discern an iPhone 3G/S visitor to an iPhone 4 visitor?

Tags: php, javascript, html, mobile-safari

I want to load higher resolution pictures for iPhone 4 users, but the only way I know of detecting users is by a user-agent. But I'm under the impression that the user-agent of MobileSafari on any iOS4 phone is the same across the board.

What could I do to detect an iPhone 4?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3262432/ where the OP states that it is possible to detect screen size from js.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354246/javascript-iphone-selection/3354478#3354478

Maybe of assistance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use CSS3 media queries to detect the iPhone 4's device-pixel ratio (how many CSS pixels equal a physical display pixel). Then, you can use CSS to load higher-resolution images instead of the normal ones.

In the `<head>` tag on your web page, add this to reference an external stylesheet that will only be loaded for iPhone 4 users:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="high_res.css" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />
```

The `media` attribute specifies to only use this stylesheet for devices with a minimum device-pixel ration of 2 (ie. the iPhone 4). Then, you can add CSS rules in high_res.css to replace low-res images with high-res versions:

```
#highres-if-possible {
    background-image: url(high_res_pic.png);
}
```

Note that you will have to specify the image in HTML by using the CSS `background-image` property instead of the `src` attribute.

Example: for a 60x50 image, replace:

```
<img id="highres-if-possible" src="low_res_pic.png">
```

with

```
<img id="highres-if-possible" style="width: 60px; height: 50px; background-image: url(low_res_pic.png);">
```

No guarantee that specifying images like this will work in all browsers (Internet Explorer), but it should work fine in standards-compliant browsers (and on the iPhone).

For more info on CSS3 media queries and using them to detect the iPhone 4, see: http://blog.iwalt.com/2010/06/targeting-the-iphone-4-retina-display-with-css3-media-queries.html

**UPDATE**: I came across *[this post](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showpost.php?p=59040&postcount=12)* and [*this post*](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/forum-replies.cfm?t=693494&r=10838620#r10838620) that might have a better way to handle specifying the images using CSS (using `<img style="background-image:url(http://...)">` instead of `<img src="http://...">`) than what I have above.

Answer (score -1):

using the HTTP_USER_AGENT string you could probably figure out which one it is. I have never try it but if should get you started. Also ive seen a couple of php library that will do it for you. hope this helps.
cheers.