# Is there a way to detect if user using iphone 3GS or 4 to browse the website?

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, ios, html

I want to detect if user using iphone type lower than iphone 4 in order to run different kind

of HTML5 video because iphone 3 can only run low quality video. Can someone give me some

solution to achieve this goal. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436719/is-there-a-way-to-discern-an-iphone-3g-s-visitor-to-an-iphone-4-visitor

Comment: stumbled across this some time ago, I think it's a good way http://www.bdoran.co.uk/2010/07/19/detecting-the-iphone4-and-resolution-with-javascript-or-php/

Comment: Complete List of iOS User-Agent Strings:
http://www.enterpriseios.com/wiki/UserAgent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used this on several high traffic sites its light and does a fantastic job

http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

Answer (score 0):

On server (php):

```
<?php
if(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Apple-iPhone3C')!==false || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Apple-iPhone4C')!==false) {
    echo 'iPhone 4';
} else {
    echo 'other model';
}
```

See also: [detect in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436719/is-there-a-way-to-discern-an-iphone-3g-s-visitor-to-an-iphone-4-visitor).